# Hierarchical Edge Bundling d3 v4 - simplest 2 node example

Tags: d3.js

I would like to do the simplest Hierarchical Edge Bundling example I can, with two nodes. Once I fully understand how to make that work properly I should (hopefully) be able to dynamically construct the full visualization.

I saw Mike Bostock's D3 V4 example: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607999 and would like to use the same pattern. However, going through the JSON data it is a bit overwhelming. I was hoping with two nodes I could see how the visualization is constructed.

How would the JSON file look with just two nodes? I am trying to make the absolute easiest I can to try and learn how it works. Any help is appreciated.

I can't paste the JSON in here because it exceeds the maximum number of characters. For reference please check out:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607999#flare.json[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the data using 3 nodes (visualization would not have been much useful with 2 nodes):

```
var data = [{
  "name": "iit.mumbai.pub1",
  "imports": ["iit.chennai.pub3"]
}, {
  "name": "iit.delhi.pub2",
  "imports": ["iit.mumbai.pub1"]
}, {
  "name": "iit.chennai.pub3",
  "imports": ["iit.delhi.pub2"]
}];
```

Here is how it would look:
https://gist.github.com/ckothari/473320621a15a7ee1ed684bf3feb4255

I have taken example of academic publications in the above example. The dots in the names represent the hierarchal relationships, so in this example `iit` (Institute) has 3 children (locations) `mumbai`, `delhi` and `chennai`, and these have children (publications) `pub1`, `pub2` and `pub3` respectively.

`imports` in the json represents relation between the leaf nodes. Publication `pub1` has citation for publication `pub3`, `pub2` cites `pub1` and `pub3` cites `pub2`.

Comment: You sir, are a rock star. Thank you. By the way, I wanted to use the name "4.5.2" and it doesn't work. I have to use a '-' or a '_' character instead of a '.'. Do you know how to change that?

Comment: Check packageHierarchy function, replacing "." in name.lastIndexOf(".") with "-" should do it.

Answer (score 0):

To add further explanation to accepted answer for beginners.

Let's assume we have 3 nodes (3 publications) connected to each other.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "name": "pub1",
    "imports": [ "pub3" ]
  },
  {
    "name": "pub2",
    "imports": [ "pub1" ]
  },
  {
    "name": "pub3",
    "imports": [ "pub2" ]
  }
];
```

It looks like same as accepted answer.
https://bl.ocks.org/ckothari/raw/473320621a15a7ee1ed684bf3feb4255/.

To group further based on origin of publications, we can use `.` notation to represent hierarchal relationships.

Assume `pub1` & `pub2` belong to college `abc`. And `pub3` belongs to college `xyz`.

Now the data looks like,

```js
const data = [
  {
    "name": "abc.pub1",
    "imports": [ "xyz.pub3" ]
  },
  {
    "name": "abc.pub2",
    "imports": [ "abc.pub1" ]
  },
  {
    "name": "xyz.pub3",
    "imports": [ "abc.pub2" ]
  }
];
```

In the graph, `pub1` & `pub2` will lie close to each other as they belong to same pareent.